# CSS: :first-line pseudo-element render error on resize in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, css-selectors, render

There seems to be a bug in Google Chrome that renders the first-line pseudo-element in a wrong way once the user starts to resize the browser window.

In my case I use a horizontal line as a background-image in the actual element and I use the first-line pseudo-element to give a white background to the heading. This is an attempt to omit having to use a second element to make the same happen, because this will be user-generated content and I don't want to complicate things for them.

Here are two images that demonstrate my issue.

This is how it is correctly rendered:

[image: Google Chrome first-line correct render]

And this is what happens when I resize the window:

[image]

My CSS:

```
h2 {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(../images/Template/border.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0% 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h2:first-line  {
        background-color: #fff;
}

h2:before  {
    content: '';
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippet that demonstrates the issue? We can't test, because we don't have your background image.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle, but for some reason it seems to work fine in there... https://jsfiddle.net/oxrzecLn/2/

Comment: @GeirrBenayahu If that works. Then we can't solve your internal issue..

Comment: On this website it also happens: http://www.reyer-lafeber.nl/merken The specific heading is located after the first paragraph.

Comment: I can see the difference between the browsers on the page, yes. Looks like a bug; it's not Javascript related at least (with Javascript turned off, it also happens). So the only thing I can recommend is to research the differences between the page and the jsfiddle where the problem does not occur.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into it. When I find something I will update the question.